# What type of kill do I need to get a fully recharged charge meter with the Tide Turner?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

I checked the patch notes recently on the new Tide Turner, and according to the notes, shield bash kills are now supposed to recharge your meter as well as kills from the critical hit with your sword.

Except I've noticed that I've gotten kills with Nessie's Nine-Iron and my shield equipped, yet haven't had my charge meter filled by the kill.

Whether or not the charge meter actually charges back up seems inconsistent, though maybe it's just my inconsistent 'sword' swinging that's messing me up.

So, for the record, what type of kill under what conditions must you get with the Tide Turner equipped in order to get a fully recharged charge meter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be a charge kill; either an impact kill with the shield, or a sword kill while you're charging. If you use your sword, it will mini-crit from a medium distance charge, or crit at a long distance charge. It can also crit if you swing your sword at the same time you collide with the enemy.

If you do not kill the enemy with the initial swing while charging (say you damage them on the charge swing then kill them with the following swing), you do not get the charge refill bonus.